# AngularJS - Display Item Hierarchy with Each Grouping in its own Container

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to use a `$scope` variable inside an AngularJS controller that looks like this:

```
$scope.hierarchy = {
  name: 'bob',
  selected: true,
  children: [
    { name: 'frank' },
    {
      name: 'spike',
      children: [
        { name: 'mike' },
        { name: 'ben' },
        { name: 'gloria' },
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'lisa',
      selected: true,
      children: [
        { name: 'bobby' },
        { name: 'carol' },
        { name: 'roger' },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

to populate a template. The catch is, I want to list everything at one level in one box, with a new box for the selected item's children (think OSX Finder's folder browsing).

So ideally, I would have an angular template that would render something that looks like this:

```
+------+ +--------+ +-------+
| >bob | |  frank | | bobby |
+------+ |  spike | | carol |
         | >lisa  | | roger |
         +--------+ +-------+
```

This seems like a simple task on the surface, but I'm either too thick to think of the solution or the problem is harder than it looks. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what have you tried?  what are you stuck on?  Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: I left out things I have tried to keep from leading anyone seeing the problem for the first time. The solution should be a typical AngularJS template file consisting of some kind of recursion using ng-repeat I would guess.

Comment: You can start here: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/SXFC9/

Answer (score 0):

Based on Cherniv's example, 
[here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDUVy/). Just change the layout, you can see that if you put the 'selected: true' on spike instead of lisa it adjusts correctly.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.children">
            {{data.name}}
            <ul>
                <span ng-switch on="data.selected">
                <div ng-switch-when="true" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'">
                </li>
                </span>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>

<div ng-controller="TreeController">
    <div ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'">
    </div>
</div>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        children: [{
          name: 'bob',
          selected: true,
          children: [
            { name: 'frank' },
            {
              name: 'spike',
              children: [
                { name: 'mike' },
                { name: 'ben' },
                { name: 'gloria' },
              ]
            },
            {
              name: 'lisa',
              selected: true,
              children: [
                { name: 'bobby' },
                { name: 'carol' },
                { name: 'roger' },
              ]
            }
          ]
        }]
    }

}]);
```

Comment: This is still putting the children inside the previous container.

Comment: What do you mean? It's like your example only different layout

Comment: Looking at the fiddle, you can see where the first `ul` contains the second `ul` which contains the third `ul`, and so on. I want each container to be independent of its predecessor.